# Problema con UPDATE EN mySQL

Tags: php

Me está ocurriendo algo que no alcanzo a entender. Tengo un formulario que tiene dos inputs del tipo button, aparte de otros campos para rellenar. Estos dos botones tienen dos acciones distintas, uno para mostrar una vista previa y otro para guardar los cambios del artículo.

El formulario resumido sería así:

```
<form class="inicio_sesion" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $ruta ?>editar_articulo.php?ID=<?php echo $id ?>" method="post">

   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $post['ID'] ?>"

   <input class="submit" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Guardar cambios">
   <input class="submit" type="submit" name="previa" value="Vista previa">

</form>
```

Por otra parte la información la recibo en PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar']) AND $conexion) {

$creador = isset($_POST['creador']) ? $_POST['creador'] : 'Egoi Cantero';
$categoria = isset($_POST['categoria']) ? $_POST['categoria'] : 'Articulo';
$juego = isset($_POST['juego']) ? $_POST['juego'] : 'Ninguno';
$plataforma = isset($_POST['plataforma']) ? $_POST['plataforma'] : 'Xbox One';

$titulo = trim($_POST['titulo']);
$publicado = $creador;
$id = $_POST['id'];
$categoria = $categoria;
$thumb = $_FILES['thumb'];
$articulo = $_POST['articulo'];
$etiquetas = $_POST['etiqueta'];

echo $articulo;

$hay_ya_foto = false;

//miramos si la foto ya se ha subido, si el hidden de foto guardada tiene un valor es que ya se ha subido
//cogemos el valor de ese input para meterlo en la base de datos
if (empty($thumb_db)) {
    $thumb = $_POST['foto_hidden'];
    $hay_ya_foto = true;
}

if (empty($titulo)) {
    $errores .= "El título es obligatorio </br>";
} else {
    if (strlen($titulo) > 90) {
        $errores .= "El título no puede tener más de 70 caracteres </br>";
    }
}

if (empty($publicado)) {
    $errores .= "Es obligatorio indicar el autor del artículo </br>";
}

if (empty($publicado)) {
    $errores .= "Por favor introduce etiquetas para catalogar el artículo </br>";
}

if (empty($articulo)) {
    $errores .= "El artículo está vacío </br>";
}

if (empty($errores)) {

    echo $articulo;
    $statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE art SET
        plataforma = :plataforma,
        juego_asociado = :juego_asociado,
        titulo = :titulo,
        thumb = :thumb,
        publicado_por = :publicado,
        etiquetas = :etiquetas,
        categoria = :categoria,
        articulo = :articulo
    WHERE id = $id");
    echo $articulo;
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':plataforma' => $plataforma,
        ':juego_asociado' => $juego,
        ':titulo' => $titulo,
        ':thumb' => $thumb,
        ':publicado' => $publicado,
        ':etiquetas' => $etiquetas,
        ':categoria' => $categoria,
        ':articulo' => $articulo
    ));

    //header("Location: " . $ruta . "index_admin.php");
}
```

}

Si voy a editar el artículo y no pulso sobre vista previa, toda la información se actualiza bien en la base de datos, pero si antes de guardar los cambios le doy al botón de vista previa, la información no se actualiza.

Pongo un ejemplo de lo que me está pasando. Imagino que tengo el texto del artículo como "Hola Mundo!". Tengo dos `echo $articulo` en el código para ver qué es su valor, justo después de recogerlo por POST y justo antes de introducirlo en la base de datos, y curiosamente el valor de la variable `$articulo` es correcto, pero en la base de datos no me actualiza nada.

Tampoco me arroja ningún error, he comprobado todos los datos con echo y están bien, no entiendo por qué no se actualizan los datos si en vez de cambiar el artículo y guardarlo le doy a vista previa. Aclaro que no actualiza ninguno de los campos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hace un var_dump a la variable statement, puede que alguna de las variables que tienes ahi no coincida con la base de datos y statement arroje FALSE

Comment: No me estaba cogiendo bien el valor donde tenía que hacer el UPDATE. ¡Gracias!